# How can I annotate an image with arrow and text?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using LaTeX to make a manual. I would like to annotate an image with arrows pointing to parts of the image and a textual annotation outside of the image. Is there a simple way I can do this with TikZ or something similar?

[image: an example of the kind of thing i want to do]

The question is not answered already... the linked "duplicate" (which I had seen) doesn't describe drawing arrows with text annotations, which is what i asked about!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). If the linked question doesn't answer you question please update the question and explain why.

Comment: please see my update... "Drawing on an image with Tikz" doesn't talk about arrows or text annotation

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/5764)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz) to place and node and add any additional drawings to it. You can add text via a `\node` and then use `\draw` to draw the arrows to the appropriate place on the image:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] (note) at (-1,3) {\Large Note};
\node [anchor=west] (water) at (-1,1) {\Large Water};
\begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{../images/EiffelWide.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.48,0.80) rectangle (0.55,0.95);
        \draw [-latex, ultra thick, red] (note) to[out=0, in=-120] (0.48,0.80);
        \draw [-stealth, line width=5pt, cyan] (water) -- ++(0.4,0.0);
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 20):

As already suggested, you can annotate the different parts of the figure [using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9561/76206). However, sometimes it might even better to use numbers to reference the different parts and explain them in the figure caption.

To easily **get the precise relative positions** (which is often quite tedious) and to generate LaTeX code automatically for such example as shown below, you could use the new web-based [**LaTeX Overlay Generator**](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/), which I built for such cases. This is just a small interactive tool, which helps you to find the right locations without using a manual [grid-based approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/76206).

[image: Example]

## LaTeX Code

In the following the source code of a minimal working example generated by the [**LaTeX Overlay Generator**](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/).

```
\documentclass{article}

% remove "[demo]" if you want include actual image!!!
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LaTeX Overlay Generator - Annotated Figures v0.0.1
% Created with http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\annotatedFigureBoxCustom{bottom-left}{top-right}{label}{label-position}{box-color}{label-color}{border-color}{text-color}
\newcommand*\annotatedFigureBoxCustom[8]{\draw[#5,thick,rounded corners] (#1) rectangle (#2);\node at (#4) [fill=#6,thick,shape=circle,draw=#7,inner sep=2pt,font=\sffamily,text=#8] {\textbf{#3}};}
%\annotatedFigureBox{bottom-left}{top-right}{label}{label-position}
\newcommand*\annotatedFigureBox[4]{\annotatedFigureBoxCustom{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{white}{white}{black}{black}}
\newcommand*\annotatedFigureText[4]{\node[draw=none, anchor=south west, text=#2, inner sep=0, text width=#3\linewidth,font=\sffamily] at (#1){#4};}
\newenvironment {annotatedFigure}[1]{\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) { #1};\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]}{\end{scope}\end{tikzpicture}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h!t]

        \begin{annotatedFigure}
            {\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{black-demo.png}}
            \annotatedFigureBox{0.084,0.614}{0.394,0.804}{A}{0.084,0.614}%bl
            \annotatedFigureBox{0.222,0.284}{0.3743,0.4934}{B}{0.3743,0.4934}%tr
            \annotatedFigureBox{0.555,0.784}{0.6815,0.874}{C}{0.555,0.784}%bl
            \annotatedFigureBox{0.557,0.322}{0.8985,0.5269}{D}{0.8985,0.5269}%tr
        \end{annotatedFigure}

        \caption{\textbf{Lorum Ipsum Overview} -- Lorem ipsum dolor amet (A), consetetur (B) elitr, sed diam (C) nonumy eirmod invidunt ut labore (D).}
        \label{fig:teaser}

    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) As far as possible you should try and make your answers self-contained, without deferring the real information to external links.

Comment: Right! I've added the full source code for a minimal working example to generate the include figure.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this tool. This is extremely useful. It even works oob in Beamer slides.