# Annotate figure with a text box and and arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, floats, annotations

There exists a really good [prototype](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186476/26232) for the question I'm asking. Having a look at it will be easier to understand the problem.

How would we add "Note" in a box, and have an arrow pointing to the top of the tower?

Something similar to this

[image]

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25904/26232) seems to help, but it creates a LONG box, which doesn't make it clear on beamer.

MWE

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [anchor=west] (note) at (6.0,4) {
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{11em}
        FOOBARBAZ FOOBARBAZ FOOBARBAZ
\end{minipage}}};

\begin{scope}[xshift=1.5cm]
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{graphs/test.pdf}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw [-latex, ultra thick, red] (note) to[out=0, in=90] (0.68,0.70);
        %\draw[blue,thick,rounded corners] (0.2,1.0) rectangle (0.1,0.15);
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us a MWE what you tried so far.

Comment: Added, but I do not want to put a box around every figure manually. is there some way to automate it?

Comment: This is not really a MWE, rather code sniped. Pleas make this code fragment as complete document with `\documentclass{...}` on the star, necessary packages in preamble and on the end `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can find some tips and tricks for a MWE [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `node` with some text in it to an arrow. Hopefully this will get you started. If not, please provide a minimum working example.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->, thick] node[draw, text width=3cm, above] 
         {Enter your text here. Adjust the \texttt{text width} to change the size of the box.} 
         (0,0)--++(0, -2);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]