# How to superimpose two images in a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, positioning, arrows, shapes

Even I am familiar with LaTeX I consider myself new to LaTeX presentations.

- I already created the graphics / diagrams.
- I want to overlay the cloud and the arrows over the diagrams.
- The overlay should be in a second frame.

This is my code for a frame in a `beamer` class. What I exactly want is an image like the one I have uploaded. Inside the cloud I also need some text. Also the lines should be arrows. Is this possible in LaTeX `beamer`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=Figs 5Ia-g.]
\frametitle{\textbf{\textit{continued....}}}
\begin{center}
\begin{overprint}%
\only<1>{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{Fig5Ia.jpg}}%
\only<2>{\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{Fig5Ib.jpg}}%
\caption{\only<1>{\\ \footnotesize{\textcolor{Maroon0}{\textbf{The emission of cluster $^{14}$C from Fr, Ra, Ac and Th isotopes.}}}}\only<2>{\\ \footnotesize{\textcolor{Maroon0}{\textbf{The emission of cluster $^{20}$O from Ra and Th and clusters $^{18,22}$O from Th isotopes.}}}}} 
\end{overprint}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

or otherwise can I merge these two figures in a single slide as we do in ppt. One after the other, or more clearly image 1 should come fist and after a pause image 2 (may be as a background) [image]

Comment: see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186476/36296

Comment: or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359071/36296

Comment: or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/how-can-should-i-include-annotated-images

Comment: or http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/connecting-text-and-graphics/

Comment: And welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Please edit your title -- at the moment it's very confusing. Please describe the basic problem ion the title -- the shape name (cloud) it not important at all here, if I understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 5):

> In order to get help here, it is expected that you provide at least
> some `minimal` but compilable code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% ------------ Frame Start ------------
\begin{frame}[c]
\frametitle{Frame Title}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{center}

\pause

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture] 
\node at (current page.north east) 
    [
    anchor=north east,
    xshift=0mm,
    yshift=0mm
    ] 
{
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
% ------------ Frame End ------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compile twice!

Instead of `\pause` you can probably use other commands like `\only` and `\uncover` too., Please read the `beamer` manual for more information.

Comment: Hai Dr. Manuel and samcarter..Thank u for the quick reply. I have gone through those links. But I think I am not so clear with my question. I exactly want an image as shown above. I have two images. One is without that cloud and arrows, and the other is only the cloud and arrows. First I want to show the image 1 alone and then animate the second one on the first image as an explanation. Can I do it?

Comment: @PriyankaBalan You can put the code of the cloud and stuff in `\only` (not tested). Or you just repeat the code for the diagrams and add the cloud and so on (works every time, more manual). To be clear, do you want to create the pictures or do you want to show two already created pictures after each other?

Comment: yeah...I want to show two already created pictures one over the other...without fading the fist image (i.e. image two should be over the image 1 as an explanation). I have made the question more specific...please check and help me...its for my PhD defence.

Comment: Can u also suggest a method to draw those arrows and cloud in the exact position as in the image?

Comment: @PriyankaBalan I don't have enough time now. Try so use the proposed solution and if you have enough time left then ask another question here. But please make sure that you provide a decent minimal code example without the custom / additional stuff that has nothing to do with the problem. See my code for example. Providing a minimal code example can take some time but it's worth it. It also helps you to understand the problem better and it's easier to adapt the solution in the future and it's easier for others to heklp.

Comment: Ok Dr. Manuel..I think Ur answer is helpful. I should have given a detail on my coding...sorry for that...anyways thank u for sparing some time....

Comment: @PriyankaBalan Then please accept the answer so that it question is flagged solved.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{overpic}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize, series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{caption}{fg=brown}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{continued....}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{overpic}[width=\textwidth]{rexK7}
        \put(37,15){\includegraphics<2>[width=.67\textwidth]{J9rPO}}
    \end{overpic}
    \caption{The emission of cluster $^{14}$C from Fr, Ra, Ac and Th isotopes.}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]