# Superimpose two images in an article

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, article

I am trying to adapt [How to superimpose two images in a beamer presentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359786/how-to-superimpose-two-images-in-a-beamer-presentation) to a document type `article`.

The goal is to have two superimposed images in the document:
[image]

To this end I modified the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{center}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \node at (current page.north east)
          [
            anchor=north east,
            xshift=0mm,
            yshift=0mm
          ]
          {
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
          };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

There is a difficulty in modifying the wording `current page`. It should be `current "figure"`, but I don't know how to properly describe it in Latex.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you put both images into the same `tikzpicture`?

Comment: It would be nice to know how to do it

Comment: See @AboAmmar 's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TikZ solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(a){\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node at (a.north east)
    [
    anchor=center,
    xshift=0mm,
    yshift=0mm
    ]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `\stackinset`.  The following invocation says to inset image B, at a distance `-.1\textwidth` from the right and `-.1\textwidth` from the top of image A.

For negative-distance insets (that extend outside the border of the base image) the left-right centering of the base image is not affected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\stackinset{r}{-.1\textwidth}{t}{-.1\textwidth}
  {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
  {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To position the second picture relative to the `current "figure"`, just name the first picture `picA` and put `\node at (picA.north east)` in the same `tikzpicture`. @AlexG pointed out the same idea in a comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}    
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(picA){\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
  \node at (picA.north east){\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
  \end{tikzpicture}    
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]