# Centre of a tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

The following code due to @domenico-camasta

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(a){\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node at (a.north east)
    [
    anchor=center,
    xshift=0mm,
    yshift=0mm
    ]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

produces the following result
[image]

See also [Superimpose two images in an article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376281/superimpose-two-images-in-an-article)

How do I need to rewrite

```
a.north east
```

in the  example above if I would like image B to be placed:

1) in the centre of image A

2) in the centre east of image A?

Comment: 1. `a.center`. 2. I don't quite understand what you  mean, are you after `a.east`?

Comment: not north east but center east

Comment: Right, so `a.east`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look in chapter 72 of the [tikz and pgf manual](http://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) about the `shape` library. There you'll find a list of node shapes and for each of them a diagram with the predefined anchors is shown, similar to this for the default `rectangle` shape:

[image]

(Note that the `10` and `130` anchors are just examples, you can use any degree between 0 and 360.)

Hence, you're after the `center` and `east` anchors, as in the code below.

Note also that you probably want to set `inner sep=0` for the `a` node, to remove the "padding" between the node content and the border.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [inner sep=0] (a){\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \node at (a.north east)
    [
    anchor=center,
    xshift=0mm,
    yshift=0mm
    ]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    };
    \node at (a.center) {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}};
    \node at (a.east) {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. That picture from page 67 should be compulsory reading!

Answer (score 3):

The default positioning is using `center` and the default anchor is `center`, so just `node at (a)` will put the node at `a.center`. The center east position is just `east`, accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(a)[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \node at (a)
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    }
    node at (a.east)
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]