# How to graph boxes and texts within an image

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, positioning

I'm trying to do the following but it has not occurred to me what package to use, over there I heard Tiks:
[image]

Comment: That's Visual Studio -- VB.NET environment!

Comment: [How can I annotate an image with arrow and text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186389/134144) and [How can/should I include annotated images?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1449/134144) might be helpful.

Comment: It's hard for me to make squares, is there any way to create them?