# tikz: How to annotate a picture created with gnuplot's epslatex terminal?

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, annotations

I know how to annotate a picture using \node and includegraphics, [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186389/how-can-i-annotate-an-image-with-arrow-and-text).
But I need to include a pic createed with gnuplot and epslatex terminal.
The resulting *.tex looks something like this (shortened):

```
% GNUPLOT: LaTeX picture with Postscript
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package color not loaded in conjunction with
      terminal option `colourtext'%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{Either use 'blacktext' in gnuplot or load the package
      color.sty in LaTeX.}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
    \GenericError{(gnuplot) \space\space\space\@spaces}{%
      Package graphicx or graphics not loaded%
    }{See the gnuplot documentation for explanation.%
    }{The gnuplot epslatex terminal needs graphicx.sty or graphics.sty.}%
    \renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPcolor}{%
    \newif\ifGPcolor
    \GPcolortrue
  }{}%
  \@ifundefined{ifGPblacktext}{%
    \newif\ifGPblacktext
    \GPblacktexttrue
  }{}%
  % define a \g@addto@macro without @ in the name:
  \let\gplgaddtomacro\g@addto@macro
  % define empty templates for all commands taking text:
  \gdef\gplbacktext{}%
  \gdef\gplfronttext{}%
  \makeatother
  \ifGPblacktext
....
\begin{picture}(7200.00,5040.00)%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplbacktext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
      \put(2034,4534){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}(a)}}%
      \put(983,3955){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\strut{}(a)}}%
    }%
    \gplgaddtomacro\gplfronttext{%
      \csname LTb\endcsname%%
...
    \gplbacktext
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics{mypath/mypic.eps}}%
    \gplfronttext
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup
```

This needs to be included via "input" .
So how can I embed this kind of picture within the tikzpicture environment and annotate it?

Answer (score 2):

### Prologue

I guess you won't find many users here who use gnuplot with latex regularly.

If you want to create plots that integrate well into your document you find alternatives which follow a more tex'ish approach with a larger user base like `pgfplots`.

However it's not impossible to create high quality graphs with gnuplot and latex.

I don't think that either the `epslatex`, the `cairolatex` or the `pdf` terminal of gnuplot is qualified for this task though. Since all of these terminals create self-contained "images" from gnuplot files. This approach doesn't contribute to a well typeset document.

In contrast gnuplot's `latex` and `tikz` terminals don't create self-contained images but latex code from which latex compiles the final graphs. The resulting output is of far higher typographical quality.

The following example shows how to integrate graphs created with gnuplot's `tikz` terminal into your document and how to annotate the graph.

It uses `siunitx` to typeset numbers, `gnuplot-lua-tikz` which is provided by `gnuplot` and `gnuplottex` which supports to create graphs with gnuplot from a single tex-file.

#### Simple Way to Annotate Gnuplot's Output (tikz-Terminal)

The annotation takes place within the `tikzpicture` environment. All nodes of the plot are annotated after the `gnuplot` environment.

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve but for merely  annotating the graph this approach should do it.

I hope the code is as self-explanatory as possible for you.

But for motivational purposes the compiled output first. As you can see the font is consistent over the whole page.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[siunitx]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzset{
    tick style/.style = {
        black, inner sep=1ex, rounded corners=0.4ex, font=\small, 
    },
    gp node right/.append style = {
        tick style, fill=red!20, font=\footnotesize
    },
    gp node center/.append style = {
        tick style, fill=green!20, yshift=-3ex
    }
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{gnuplot}[
            terminal=tikz, 
            terminaloptions={
                color size 10,8 nopicenvironment originreset tightboundingbox createstyle
            }
        ]
            set yrange [-2:2]
            set ytics 1.0
            set samples 500
            set key spacing 2.5
            set zeroaxis
            set grid xtics
            set grid ytics
            plot [-10:10] 10**-2*sin(4*x)*x**2 lw 4 t '$10^{-2}x^2\sin{4x}$',\
            3/(1+exp(-x))-1.5 ls 2  lt 3 t '$\displaystyle \frac{3}{1+\exp{-x}}-1.5$'

        \end{gnuplot}

        % Create all labels
        \foreach \i/\j in {%
            {west}/{left}, {north west}/{above left},
            {north}/{above}, {north east}/{above right},
            {east}/{right}, {south east}/{below right},
            {south}/{below}, {south west}/{below left},
            {center}/{above}%
        } {
            \fill[red] (gp plot 1.\i) circle[radius=1mm] node[\j, text=black, fill=white, fill opacity=0.6, text opacity=1, inner sep=2ex]{\i};
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Gnuplot tikz terminal in action}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

#### Smart Way to Annotate Gnuplot's Output (tikz-Terminal)

Unfortunately i don't have much time today. But i would like to point out that it's possible to define reference nodes in gnuplot's coordinate system which can later be referred to from your latex document.

The feature is poorly documented in the official reference manual. It says:

> The  string may contain any valid TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt font 
>   commands like e.g.  ’\small’.  It is  passed  directly  as  a  node  parameter  in  form  of "font={}".   This  can  be  ’misused’  to add further  code  to  a  node,  e.g.   ’\small,yshift=1ex’  or  ’,yshift=1ex’  are  also  valid  while  the  latter  does  notchange  the  current  font  settings.

The crucial information is in `gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex`:

> to add an empty label with the referenceable name "my node"
>   to the plot, just add the following line to your gnuplot
>   file:
>
> `set label "" at 1,1 font ",gp refnode,name=my node"`

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[hmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[siunitx]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\usetikzlibrary{ducks}

\xsavebox{duck}{%
    \tikz{\draw (0,0) pic[duck/body=black!20!magenta] {duck};}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        aux line style/.style = {
            ->, thick, shorten >=4pt, >=stealth, 
        },
        circled number style/.style = {
           circle, thick, fill=orange!20, draw=black
        }
    ]
        \begin{gnuplot}[
            terminal=tikz, 
            terminaloptions={
                color size 14,11 nopicenvironment originreset tightboundingbox createstyle
            }
        ]
            set yrange [-2:2]
            set ytics 1.0
            set samples 750
            set zeroaxis
            set grid xtics
            set grid ytics

            f1(x) = 10**-2*sin(2*pi*x/(2))*x**2

            set label "" at 2,1.6 font ",gp refnode, name=annotate"
            set label "" at -9.5,f1(-9.5) font ",gp refnode, name=p1"

            set label "" at 0,-1.5 font ",gp refnode, name=p2"

            set for [j=0:8] label "" at 2*j-8.5,f1(2*j-8.5) font sprintf(",gp refnode, name=n%d", j)
            set for [j=0:8] label "" at 2*j-7.5,f1(2*j-7.5) font sprintf(",gp refnode, name=d%d", j)

            plot [-10:10]   f1(x) lw 4 t ''

        \end{gnuplot}

        \draw (annotate) node[circled number style]{1} edge[aux line style, out=-180, in=90] (p1);

        \begin{scope}[overlay]
            \node[circled number style] (2) at ([shift={(6,-5)}]gp plot 1.south) {2};
            \foreach \i in {0,1,...,8}{
                \draw[aux line style, green!40!black]  (2) edge[in=-90, out=90] (n\i);
                \fill[red, draw=black] (n\i) circle[radius=1mm];
            }
        \end{scope}

        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,8}{
            \node[
                scale=0.4,
                anchor=south, 
                inner sep=-2pt, 
                rotate={30*mod(\i,3)-30}
            ] at (d\i) {\xusebox{duck}}; 
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}\medskip

    \caption{Gnuplot tikz terminal in action}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I really appreciate it. My reasoning behind using gnuplot is simply performance. Especially when I need to annotate a surface plot with arrows and labels it is really annoying to wait 1 min. and more for a single plot. Gnuplot is several orders of magnitude faster and the quality is good enough for me.

Comment: @ODIUM I Updated my answer! I have discovered how to define nodes in gnuplot to which you can later refer to from your latex document. Would be interesting to know if you can reproduce my example.